# Ruby variable from outer scope undefined within a block - why?

Tags: ruby

This part of code dynamically creates several classes:

```
(1..MAX_ACT).each do |act_id|
  klass = Class.new(ActB) do
    def initialize(trg)
      super(trg, act_id)
    end
  end
  Object.const_set("Act#{act_id}", klass)
end
```

In this case, the common base class (`ActB`) has a constructor with two parameters, while the child classes have a constructor with one parameter.

Running this code works well, but when I later try to instantiate one of these classes, for example

```
Act3.new(4)
```

I get the error message

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `act_id' for #<Act3:0x00000006008b7990>
```

The error message must refer to the line

```
super(trg, act_id)
```

because this is the only place in my program where I am **using** this variable. However, this variable is defined a few lines above, when it says

```
(1..MAX_ACT).each do |act_id|
```

I had expected, that the *do...end* block creates a closure for the constructor, where *act_id* is bound. However, this doesn't seem to be the case.

Why does my example not work? How do I have to do it correctly?

Answer (score 4):

`def` (and `class` and `module`) creates a fresh local scope, which doesn't inherit any locals from outside.

So you're right that the `Class.new do .. end` creates a closure... but the inner `def` doesn't share it.

If you need standard block behaviour, you can use `define_method` instead:

```
(1..MAX_ACT).each do |act_id|
  klass = Class.new(ActB) do
    define_method :initialize do |trg|
      super(trg, act_id)
    end
  end
  Object.const_set("Act#{act_id}", klass)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, there is a hack, allowing to fool scoping and still use `def initialize` :)

```
class ActB
  def initialize(trg, act_id)
    puts "ActID: #{act_id}"
  end 
end
(1..MAX_ACT).each do |act_id|
  klass = Class.new(ActB) do
    @act_id = act_id
    def initialize(trg)
      super(trg, self.class.instance_variable_get(:@act_id))
    end 
  end 
  Object.const_set("Act#{act_id}", klass)
end

Act1.new :foo
#⇒ ActID: 1
Act2.new :foo
#⇒ ActID: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the block passed to `Class.new` is executed in the context of that class. In the context of that class, `act_id` is not defined. So, to fix this, you can move the method definition outside of the class initialization, like so:

```
(1..MAX_ACT).each do |act_id|
  klass = Class.new(ActB)
  klass.define_method(:initialize) do |trg|
    super(trg, act_id)
  end
  Object.const_set("Act#{act_id}", klass)
end
```

Comment: This is wrong, and both other answers prove that in the context of the class `act_id` is perfectly visible.